# iPhone: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString gives wrong output

Tags: iphone

I am showing a web page using html string in a UIWebview. I want to retrieve the value typed from the below text area code.

```
result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"<textarea name=\"qId_"];
    NSString *questionid = [question valueForKey:@"QuestionId"];
    NSString *questionidSTR = (NSString *) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", questionid];
    result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:questionidSTR];
    [questionidArray addObject:questionidSTR];
    result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"\" rows=\"5\" style=\"width:90%\"></textarea>"];
```

I tried

```
NSString  *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"document.getElementById('",[questionidArray objectAtIndex:i],@"').value"];

   NSString* out = [enterSurveyWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:value];
```

But, its not giving the correct output, i think i'm doing wrong when retrieving the value.

Could someone please correct me for retrieving portion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<textarea>` has a name of `qId_%@` (where `%@` is the `QuestionId`), but your javascript is only asking for `%@`. You also need to be using `getElementByName()` instead of `getElementById()`.

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('qId_%@')[0].value", [questionidArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: I tried correcting it, result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@qId_%@%@",@"document.getElementById('",[questionidArray objectAtIndex:i],@"').value"];  but its not getting the value.

Comment: @Getsy: I think you want `getElementByName()`

Comment: Sorry, make that `getElementsByName()`.

Comment: Either result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementByName('%@').value", [questionidArray objectAtIndex:i]]; (or) result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementByName('qId_%@').value", [questionidArray objectAtIndex:i]];  , both are not giving the actual result.